# How to change "Favorite Tags" background color?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks, firefox

I have a hard time seeing this color, maybe because of my screen or my eyes. Could it be changed somehow? maybe to #C1EFF9 or any other color that is darker than currently.

Maybe best if the site could be customized.

Comment: This color can't be changed, unless you modify the CSS yourself

Comment: I like your color choice by the way. I'll keep it ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use any CSS customization browser extension and change the style of `.tagged-interesting`, e.g.

```
.tagged-interesting {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Make sure you declare your changes `!important` so they don't get overridden by the site style.

[image: Screenshot of effect of user CSS]

---

To customize the presentation of ignored tags, change the style of `.tagged-ignored`.

Comment: Can this be done in EditCSS for firefox? i tried EditCSS to change the color (without using "!important") and it doesnt remember my changes when i close the browser. Edit: actually i dont even need to close the browser; just change the page and its all gone.

Comment: @Rookie I don't think it's supposed to. It seems to be a tool for web designers wanting to test CSS changes on the fly. Read the comments on the downloads page.

Comment: ChromEditPlus (http://webdesigns.ms11.net/chromeditp.html) worked good with your code.

Answer (score 4):

### Google Chrome

- [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha)

### Firefox

- [EditCSS](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/editcss/)
- [Editing userContent.css](http://coreygilmore.com/blog/2008/10/23/per-site-custom-css-in-firefox/)
- [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/)

### Safari

- [User CSS](http://code.grid.in.th/)

Comment: EditCSS doesnt work? When i close my browser, i need to edit everything again.

Comment: Actually, EditCSS forgets my settings even when just going from one page to another. Am i doing something wrong here...?

Comment: @Rookie: Sorry, I only use Stylebot myself.

Comment: @Rookie Check out my suggestions for Firefox in this answer. Stylish works like a charm.

Comment: @DanielBeck, ChromEditPlus works too. I used your code with it and works good! Does it always require browser restart to apply changes to CSS?

Comment: @Rookie If you use the wrong plugin, it might. Works immediately with Stylish. Also, feel free to add suggestions to Oliver's answer, that's why it's *community wiki*...

Comment: @Rookie If you are using Firefox, I recommend the Stylish add-on. I made a quick video demonstrating Stylish (downloading, installing, and writing custom CSS) for one of my Super User answers. You can watch it here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAhzZuhN61E

Comment: Do note that the XUL namespace is not required for your case.

Comment: @iglvzx, nice, might be useful. i already switched to stylish though.